# How to use nullif() function on update hql statement in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I want to do an update on a certain column in my table in the database and do some simple arithmetic operation like add.But my column is `nullable`.
So in order not to have a error i need to check first if it is null.
I bump into `nullif` function in hibernate but i don't know the usage of this.
Anybody know the usage of `nullif`?

I wanted to use this in update `HQL` statement to check if the column is null and then perform an addition on the field.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

the signature is `nullif(column, "valueifcolumn is null")`

so in update do `Update x set x.y = nullif(x.z, 0) + 123`

Comment: its not working with me..Is it working on you? :( the `executeUpdate` returns 1 but the table is not updated to increment.

Comment: i can only test it here with NHibernate and sqlite. it doesnt see a null int as null and will always take the original null value. maybe addition then fails. if the property is non null it increments just fine

Comment: i read that the nullif works only on the WHERE clause.But thanks anyway. :)